# mysql query: get sum of all values of colum2 belonging to distinct values of column1

Tags: mysql

```
item_id     issued_quantity             issued_datetime
10613               10                  9/20/2016 11:14
11259               15                  9/20/2016 11:14
50                  30                  9/20/2016 11:14
10613               10                  9/20/2016 11:18
94                  20                  9/20/2016 11:18
10606               7                   9/20/2016 11:18
3                   10                  9/20/2016 11:27
10613               10                  9/20/2016 11:28
197                 30                  9/20/2016 11:28
10606               5                   9/20/2016 11:29
```

These are the some columns of a table item_issue
The data given here for only one day.
There is data in the table for multiple days.

I wish to create a query which will list the sum of quantity 
for each item_id on a day, for multiple days

e.g 
A query which will give the following output(for the above data):

```
item_id         issued_quantity     
10613               30              
11259               15              
50                  30              
94                  20
10606               12
3                   10                          
197                 30
```

Please guide me. I just know basic mysql commands.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to look a SQL tutorial because this is a simple query, try to learn how to do it and try different things. [Tutorial group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) I am sure you can do it by yourself, anyway, this is the answer:

```
select item_id,sum(issued_quantity)
from table1
group by item_id
```

**EDIT**
You can add in the `group by` clause, the `issued_datetime` value, but with the function `DATE()` so we just use the date part and not the time part of the column:

```
select item_id,date(issued_datetime),sum(issued_quantity)
from table1
group by item_id,date(issued_datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution Nacho. Perhaps I did not explain my query clearly. The query you provided will give the sum of all the quantities at one shot,irrespective of date. IF there are 50 different items in the table, your query will result in 50 rows, . This is not what I desire. I wish to apply the same logic per item per day. If there are two items issued on a day and 3 items issued on the next day, I wish to have 5 rows in the result of the query (once of each item per day) having 2 columns-item_id and sum of quantity

Comment: I have made an edition of the answer the add the date

Comment: I had tried the query that u have given, but it did not give the result that i desired at the time. Then I saw your edit and knew I was on the right track. Then I added the clause order by date(issued_datetime), then the query was complete. Thank you very much for your help. I learned about the _group by_ and _order by_ clauses.